# Google Maps Polygons: How do you get the coordinates of predefined paths?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygons

I was given a list of links to predefined Google Map polygons like this one:

https://www.google.com/search?es_sm=91&espv=210&q=laarbeek&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=pv.xjs.s.en_US.ClVHbHStgs4.O

If you click the image on the right you will be redirected to the full map view with the shape.

Now I need to create my own map with all these shapes. Is there a way where I could get their coordinates? I've been looking for them on the page but had no luck. I'd rather not do it manually because of course, Google is more accurate.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Those polygons are not directly available using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (at least at this point).  They may be available from  http://www.gadm.org/ or in the [Natual Earth Data](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2011/02/natural-earth-vectors-in-cloud.html) (which is available via FusionTables).

Comment: Might be this [enhancement request in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109)

Comment: Thanks. I had a problem understanding gadm.org but the issue tracker lead me to a workaround. The easiest way I found is to draw the shape manually BUT with the help of tracing. In case somebody wants the same just create your own map on the Google Maps page: My Places -> "Create with classic My Maps", type in your address and click on the result. The defined shape will still show and now you can trace it! After saving you will have an option to export it as KML. Probably not the best solution, but I can live with it for now. Thanks again!